# Can not open Chrome neither via Terminal nor GUI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and cannot open chrome, when I type  `google-chrome` I get following error:

```
    root@serien:~#  google-chrome
    [10449:10449:0209/013849.529890:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] 
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. 
See https://crbug.com/638180.
    root@serien:~#
```

I use XRDP and when I connect to GUI and click under the `Application > internet > chrome` it has no efffect nothing will be opened.

I updated but can not open chrome, is any solution here?

Comment: You mention that you are using XRDP. Are you logging in as root or as a normal user? (I'm more familiar with VNC.)

Answer (score 0):

Run google chrome as user:

```
~$ google-chrome
```

Or as the error message say, use  `--no-sandbox` option as root:

```
~# google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

Comment: i use second command and got following error:root@serien:~# google-chrome --no-sandbox
[13840:13840:0209/015525.702462:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1438)] Unable to open X display.
root@serien:~# [0209/015526.047910:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(307)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly

Comment: @VanGogh You need to set X11 forwarding to run the graphical application from rdp.